# GCM stop receiving after a period of time

Tags: push-notification

Recently, I tried to use GCM service which works well.  However, if I don't use it for 1 day, it stops receiving.  I need to start the app again.  So how to avoid this?  I have checked the registration id is always the same and not the id issue.

thanks
Alex

Comment: i have to face the same problem, any solution or reason so far

Comment: @Mario Me too. Did you find any solutions?

Comment: Now once user login the app, I update the token, and seems works fine.

Comment: @Ali sorry. Like already mentioned we refresh the token and cross the fingers. Nevertless this problem was a long time ago. And i think that Google improved there GCM service quite a bit since then.

Comment: @mario Thanks for your answer.